# Hide Rows on Each Sheet before PrintPDFs Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a standard form letter that I need to print for separate employees. I'm not very experienced with macros so these are just basic ones I found online. Both work separately. The PrintPDFs macro goes through the employee number (CellWithDropdown), prints the pdf for each employee listed in EmployeeNo and saves to a specified folder. However, I want to hide certain rows that are not applicable to each employee before the pdf prints. The HideRow macro works but I need to integrate it somehow in the PrintPDFs macro. I'd appreciate any help with this!

```
Sub PrintPDFs()
Const NamedRangeName = "EmployeeNo"
Const SheetName = "Letter"
Const CellWithDropdown = "M25"
Const PrintRange = "A15:I60"
Dim rowCounter As Integer

Dim fPath As String, choice As Range, fName As String
[COLOR=#006400] 'allow user to select folder[/COLOR]
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select destination folder for PDF export"
        If .Show = -1 Then fPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

[COLOR=#006400] 'rest of code[/COLOR]
    If fPath <> "" Then
        With Sheets(SheetName)
                For Each choice In Range(NamedRangeName)
                .Range(CellWithDropdown) = choice
                 fName = choice & Format(Date, " yymmdd") & ".pdf"
                .Range(PrintRange).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fPath & "\" & fName
            Next
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No folder selected"
        
    End If

End Sub
```

```
Sub HideRow()
LineStart = 35
LineEnd = 52
ColumnNumber = 12
For i = LineStart To LineEnd
If Cells(i, ColumnNumber).Value <> "Zero" Then
Cells(i, ColumnNumber).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
Cells(i, ColumnNumber).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Depends exactly what you mean by 'integrate it' ... if you just want the `PrintPDFs` Sub to call the `HideRow` Sub then create a new, blank line at the relevant point in the `PrintPDFs` Sub and on that line type `HideRow`. However, as it stands, `HideRow` is only going to make rows visible, no rows will ever be hidden (i.e. each branch of the `If` results in the entire row being made visible as its `Hidden` property is set to False)

Comment: By integrate I mean that prior to printing a pdf for a specific "EmployeeNo", I want to hide the rows that are not relevant to that employee number.

Comment: You are correct the second false in the HideRow should be True. When I include the HideRow in the PrintPDF, it only appears to work for the first report and keeps the same rows hidden for all the rest. However I want it to run the HideRow before it prints every report.

Comment: Nevermind! I figured out where to put to the HideRow so it works! Really appreciate the help!